# <xsl:output method="text" /> produces some unwanted output

Tags: text, methods, output, xslt-1.0

I supply to customer a number of `.xslt` (XSLT 1.0) files, used to generate email message bodies.  They are designed and supplied with `<xsl:output method="**html**" />`, and all is fine.

Customer is told that if their mail system cannot handle HTML they can simply change the `.xslt` files to `<xsl:output method="**text**" />`.  All has been well.  Now I have changed so that the template includes a CSS `style` declaration like:

```
<style>
body { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 10pt; }
</style>
```

While the `text` output method correctly knows to omit the `<style>` tag lines, the output text ends up with `body { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: 10pt; }` in it, which is clearly not desired in the text mail content!

- Is there anything I can do to that fragment to prevent it being output when `method="text"`?  (I doubt it.)
- Or, is there any way an `<xsl:if test="..."` can access the output method, so that I can omit when text?

Comment: I think you are looking at it backwards. The output method is not an input to the stylesheet; it's part of the code designed to get the desired output from the (real) input. It also cannot be parametrized, AFAIK.

Comment: I don't really understand what you say above.  I understand output method is not a parameter.  Sites have to change the stylesheet (it's an application they are running, they have the sheet) to edit "html" to "text", they are happy with that.  What I am trying to do is omit the text inside <style> from appearing in the text-only output.

Comment: I am saying it's not a healthy approach to have users modify the output method and expect everything else to keep on working. If you want to give them some degree of control, then parametrize the stylesheet. An output method of xml, with the xml declaration omitted, should allow you cover all scenarios.

Comment: Interesting what you say.  I had thought it was neat/intended that an HTML output could produce a reasonable text equivalent (it had worked OK so far for me!) by just changing the output method, and it would essentially drop all the HTML tags.  I'm "glad" you said that was expecting too much!  I still don't get now what you're saying.  The user just wants to change the output from HTML to text, what parameterization are you talking about, XML to XML, that would affect this?  Are you talking about generating a new XSLT from the current one?

Comment: I am talking about the relationship between developer and users in general. If you want to give users choices, then add a (global) parameter to the styleshet, e.g. `<xsl:param name="mail-method">HTML</xsl:param>`. Then teach them how to modify that, either manually or by sending an actual parameter at runtime - and nothing else.

Comment: But I thought we just (correctly) agreed above that we cannot parameterize the `<xsl:output method="...">` statement!?  So I don't know what to do with your new `mail-method` variable/parameter --- unless you mean that I can have `<xsl:output ...>` appear more than once, inside `<xsl:choose>` based on parameter, which I did not think was allowed (e.g. cf. `<xsl:include>` or `<xsl:import>`).  If you feel this is getting long and I'm not understanding, feel free to abandon me!

Comment: My idea is to use a constant `<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>`. Then have your stylesheet use the user-supplied parameter to decide what should (or shouldn't)  be written to the output tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I don't think this is a good approach - but you *can* get the value of the output method by using the following expression:

```
document('')/*/xsl:output/@method
```

Comment: Sounds good, for my purpose.  When I try `<xsl:if test="document('')/*/xsl:output/@method1!='text'">` around the `<style>` stuff, .NET runtime gives me: `Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it.`  Am I "safe" to enable this in my .NET app?

Comment: You'll have to ask someone who knows something about .NET  :-)

Comment: Whilst I accept that this is the correct principle I was looking for, unfortunately it does not work in my situation.  The file in which the `<style>` appears and I want this test is actually a separate `.xslt` file which is `<xsl:include>`d into individual `.xslt` files for each mail message which themselves have the `<xsl:output method="...">`.  It appears that the `document('')` refers to the included document, not the including document, so it does not see the output method.

Before I mark this answer as "the solution", I don't suppose there is any argument to `document()` for this?

Comment: There may be, but I am afraid I got lost in your explanation. Perhaps you should post a new question?